# How to Validate Multiple Email Addresses in a Reactive Form in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a requirement for inputting 50 email address with a same domain name (gmail.com).

I am using a Reactive form. I have added some code that I have written form it is not working for me.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfwfow

Can anyone help me on this please?

```js
emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-,;]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.,;)?[a-zA-Z]+\.,;)?(gmail)\.com";

 ngOnInit() {
        this.accountingForm = this.fb.group({
            'day' : [null, Validators.required], 
            'email': ['',
                Validators.compose([
                    Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern),this.commaSepEmail
                ])
            ]
        });
    }
    commaSepEmail = (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
        console.log("This is value:" + control.value);
        if (!_.isEmpty(control.value)){
            var emails= control.value.split(',');
            const forbidden = emails.some((email:any) => Validators.email(new FormControl(email)));
        console.log(forbidden);
        return forbidden ? { 'email': { value: control.value.trim() } } : null;
        }
    };
```

```html
 <form [formGroup]="accountingForm" (ngSubmit)="generateSOR(accountingForm.value)">
    <input formControlName="email" [pattern]="emailPattern" placeholder="Email Address">
    <button type="submit" mat-raised-button class="mat-primary" [disabled]="!accountingForm.valid">Generate</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hi can you please give a bit more details on how it's not working? What was your expected result and what is your actual result? By providing more details it makes the life easier to anyone trying to help.

Comment: Hi @Hugo Noro, Thank you so much for your time. I have a generate button which will be enabled if I add an email address like "example@gmail.com" but the button gets disabled if I enter "example@gmail.com,test@gmail.com". It is not getting the email address after ','.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the comasepEmail function? Is it giving you the correct output?

Comment: Hi @HugoNoro. Please find the url of my code. If I am adding more than 1 email address, the generate button is getting diabaled. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfwfow

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing the link for the code. I would suggest you edit your question to include the link as part of the question, to make it easier for other people to check it. Please check my answer below and if it solves your problem don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I spotted the issue you are having with the button not being enabled. if you change your `emailPattern`

from string format

`emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-,;]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.,;)?[a-zA-Z]+\.,;)?(gmail)\.com";`

to regex format

`emailPattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-,;]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.,;)?[a-zA-Z]+\.,;)?(gmail)\.com/;`

I believe it will work. From what I was testing you might want to fine tune the regex to better achieve your expected results but this solves the issue with the button not being enabled.

I usually prefer to use regex expressions when possible instead of strings. It's also more readable.

Comment: No problem. Always glad to help.

Comment: The issue is although resolved but it was taking all the domain names. It should only take @gmail.com only, no other domain.

Comment: As I said in the answer the problem might be with your regular expression. Your initial problem was about the button not getting enabled so the answer solved your problem. The regex not matching is a different problem.

Comment: Yes you are right actually.. I am using this regular expression now. /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@gmail.com(, ?\w+([-+.']\w+)*@gmail.com)*$/

Comment: That one seems a lot cleaner and simpler :). I’m glad it worked.

Comment: Hi.. Can anyone help me like how to validate the input box which should only take 50 email addresses?

Comment: Why don’t you check the size of the array in the commaSepEmail function?

Comment: Can I have something in the regex expression to check the number? I want to disable the button if the email address is more than 50.

Comment: You can try to check regex rules. You can probably define a finite number

Comment: Have a look here it might help you https://regular-expressions.mobi/repeat.html?wlr=1

Answer (score 6):

This will validate comma separated list without spaces in between. The last comma will be ok. Example: `joe@email.co,jiffy@coke.peas`. This is the same as `joe@email.co,jiffy@coke.peas,`. Notice the final comma makes no difference. Also there is no space allowed.

```
 sendEmailForm: FormGroup;

  emailList: string [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.emailList = [];
    const toAddress = new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(/^([\w+-.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4},?)+$/)
    ]);

    this.sendEmailForm = new FormGroup({
      toAddress: toAddress
    });
  }
  extractEmailList(e){
    this.emailList = [];
    if(this.sendEmailForm.valid) {     
      let emails = e.split(',');
      emails.forEach(email => {
        if(email && email.length > 0) {
          this.emailList.push(email);
        }
      });
    }
    console.log(this.emailList);
  }
```

In the view you can add validations like below.

```
<form [formGroup]="sendEmailForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <span class="label label-primary">Email(s):</span>
      <input
      (ngModelChange)="extractEmailList($event)"
        type="text"
        [formControl]="sendEmailForm.controls['toAddress']"            
        value=""
        maxlength="150"
        name="toAddress"
        class="form-control"
      />
    </div>
    <small
    *ngIf="sendEmailForm.controls['toAddress'].hasError('required') && sendEmailForm.controls['toAddress'].touched"
    class="form-error-msg">
    Valid email is required to send an invitation.
  </small>
    <small
    *ngIf="sendEmailForm.controls['toAddress'].hasError('pattern') && sendEmailForm.controls['toAddress'].touched"
    class="form-error-msg">
    Please enter comma separated list of valid email addresses without spaces in between. No comma is required after last email.
  </small>
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!sendEmailForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary btn-simple" >Invite</button>
      <small class="form-error-msg">{{emailList.length}} email(s) will be sent.</small>
  </form>
```

In you onSubmit() method you can get values from emailList. There's no need to get it from the form.

Comment: How would you change the regex to allow for spaces between emails. Ex: `email1@gmail.com, email2@yahoo.com`